# How to write a local branch predictor?

Tags: cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I am trying to use runspec test my local branch predictor, but only find a disappointing result.
By now I have tried use a 64 terms LHT, and when the LHT is full, I use FIFO tactics replace a terms in LHT.I don't know if I use a tiny LHT or my improper replacement tactics makes it a terrible precision, anyway it's only 60.9095.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << HL; i++)
    {
        if (tag_lht[i] == (addr&(1-(1<<HL))))
        {
            addr = addr ^ LHT[i].getVal();
            goto here;
            break;
        }
    }
    index_lht = index_lht%(1<<HL);
    tag_lht[index_lht] = (addr&(1-(1<<HL)));
    LHT[index_lht] = ShiftReg<2>();
    addr = addr ^ LHT[index_lht].getVal();
    index_lht++;
here:
    for (int i = 0; i < 1 << L; i++)
    {
        if (tag[i] == (addr))
        {
            return bhist[i].isTaken();
        }
    }
    index = index % (1 << L);
    tag[index] = (addr);
    bhist[index].reset();
    return bhist[index++].isTaken();
```

Here I make some explain about the code. bhist is a table store 2-bit status about each branch instructions when the table is full, use FIFO replacement tactics. tag is where the table store address of each instruction. Besides, likely I use tag_lht to store address of each instruction that stored in LHT. Function isTaken() can easily get the predict result.

Comment: Sorry, insufficient details to understand.  Missing is the surrounding context of this code (i.e. the whole function) and the data declarations (types & globals) as well as maybe a comment or two, and even a diagram explaining how the various tables relate.

Comment: Note: `for (int i = 0; i < 1 << HL; i++)` **-->>** `for (int i = 0; i < (1 << HL); i++)`

Comment: @wildplasser, that may improve readability, but < is lower precedence than << so, won't change the operation, no?

Comment: `(addr&(1-(1<<HL)));` --<< I'd expect `(addr&((1u<<HL) -1  ));` here , assuming you intend to extract the lower bits as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys, I find that stupid mistake I make, and the code above is correct, but may not seem work prefect. The mistake bellow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << L); i++)
    {

        if (tag[i] == (addr))
        {
            if (takenActually)
            {
                LHT[j].shiftIn(1);
                bhist[i].increase();
            }
            else
            {
                LHT[j].shiftIn(0);
                bhist[i].decrease();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

But it should be like this:

for (int i = 0; i < (1 << L); i++)
{

```
        if (tag[i] == (addr))
        {
            if (takenActually)
            {
                LHT[j].shiftIn(1);
                bhist[i].increase();
            }
            else
            {
                LHT[j].shiftIn(0);
                bhist[i].decrease();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am so stupid that I waste you helpful people' s time, I spent so much time to figure out why it don't work, at first I thought that wrong variable or argument are used, now I just think I am a careless man.
Again I thank all you ardent fellows. Then I will answer the question with my full code.
PS. wish that my terrible English have not confuse anyone.:)